# How to get contract's all holders on BSC

Tags: blockchain, binance

How do I get contract's **all** holders with balances on BSC network?

- From bscsan.com you can export only top holders in CSV format
- From bitquery there's no ready method for holders. There's transfers, senders, receivers etc.. I guess you could solve the holders list somehow from this data but didn't find any example
- CovalentHQ's API has a method for this, but unfortunately it's giving timeout error if the holders list for the contract is huge (like SafeMoon with >1.7M holders). I asked their support for solution, but I guess they gave up because they stopped responding
- My latest plan was to use ethereum-etl. This was showing promise and found [an article about it](https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-query-balances-for-all-ethereum-addresses-in-bigquery-fb594e4034a7). It seems I need to get traces and transactions to be able to query for balances. But when I tried to load the traces:

```
ethereumetl export_traces --start-block 0 --end-block 500000 --provider-uri https://bsc-dataseed1.ninicoin.io --batch-size 100 --output traces.csv
```

I get following error message:

```
ValueError: {'code': -32601, 'message': 'the method trace_block does not exist/is not available'}
```

This made me think that maybe the tool does not support BSC.

So any ideas? Have been banging my head to the wall for couple days now.

Answer (score 0):

CovalentHQ's API has paging built into it. You could call it for each page of 1000 results and append each page to a file using python.

Comment: At the time I wrote the question, each 1000 result page of CovalentHQ API was giving timeout error if there were too many holders. I haven't re-tested now, because I lost interest in this project.